# jQuery var inside .after()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty basic jQuery question, but I'm still learning jQuery so I thought I can ask here:

I got this code:

```
var filter_title = $( ".option--container > input" ).attr( "title" );
    $(".option--container").after("<div>Test</div>")
```

The `<div>` is in the correct place, but now instead of "Test" I want my var `filter_title` inside the `<div>` but when I try it it just displays the var name in the `<div>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Concatenating_strings

Comment: This is _not_ actually a _“Pretty basic jQuery question”_, it is a question about the most basic parts of JavaScript syntax in general. And those you should rather learn on your own, from some good books or beginner tutorials, instead of coming here to have us teach them to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solve

```
$(".option--container").after("<div>" + filter_title + "</div>");
```